# Azure B2C Custom Policies OpenId-Configuration Error AADB2C90022

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

My application makes use of the open-id configuration end-points provided for Azure B2C, for example:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=<policy-name>`

This works fine for built-in policies. If I try to access the configuration for a custom policy, I get the below error (AADB2C90022):

[image]

This is even if I use the link generated in the Azure Portal here:

[image]

Is this supposed to work?

Comment: Hi @Matthew Cooper, correct, this does work. Have you attempted to run the custom policy using the "Run now endpoint" URL? You might have a faulty policy that is preventing the configuration metadata being returned.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPadgett, my mind was fried after a long day tweaking my base policy. I had tweaked it sufficiently that the derived policy had a claim in it that was not in the base policy. Interestingly the "Run now" endpoint worked, but I suspect if I had testing things all the way through with my application, I would have hit an error. I'll accept this as the answer if you convert your comment to an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AADB2C90022` error is caused by a faulty policy.

Test the specific policy by running the **Run now endpoint** URL before attempting to download the configuration metadata URL.